# Checkbox function to button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, boolean-operations

i have boolean function in checkbox. when the checkbox is selected and submitted it will be true. now i need a button named unblock in which when i press it first time it must be true and get submitted and the button name must change to block. and on second click it must change to false.

my controller code

```
def index
    @users = User.all
end

def edit
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:active)
end
```

my view code

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
      <% if user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :active %>
        <%= form.check_box :active %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= form.submit %>
      </div>
 <% end %>
```

Can anyone help me with it.

What I have tried

view Code

```
<% if user.active? %>    
  <%= button_to user_path(value: false), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  Unblock
  <% end %>
<%else%>
  <%= button_to user_path(value: true), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  block
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Controller code

```
def block
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(active: params[:value])
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Harini do you want only button named block and unblock instead of submit button and checkbox?

Comment: @Gabbar i want a button which must change the boolean function and then submit

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can simply do this

```
<% if user.active? %>    
  <%= button_to user_path(id: user.id, value: false), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  Unblock
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to user_path(id: user.id, value: true), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  block
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Old**

So, you need to a checkbox when you click to check that is `true` otherwise that is `false`, right? You can do this using `hiddent_field` which value by default is `false` like

```
<%= form.hidden_field :active, 'false' %>
```

so code look like this

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :active %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :active, 'false' %>
    <%= form.check_box :active, true %>
</div>
```

look when I check the checkbox and submit then params hash look like this

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UKbxyz...==", "active"=>"true", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

when unchecking the checkbox then

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UKbxyz...==", "active"=>"false", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Answer (score 0):

[butto_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) tag itself creates form so, and model's errors should not come inside `form_with` so here by i have modified your code , please have a look

```
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% if user.active? %> 
    <%= button_to user_path(value: false, id: user.id), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
      Unblock
    <% end %>
<%else%>
    <%= button_to user_path(value: true, id: user.id), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
      Block
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

At this point you would need to provide two parameter `value`, and `user` (to which user's status will be changed) with `button_to`

But the issue is on clicking the button block/unblock it will hit update action and at this action you will get `params[:value] = false` and `params[:id] = "2"`

and this won't work because at update action you are handling params in strong parameter, what i mean you are expecting `params[:user][:value]` which will return you `nil` but you are getting it as `params[:value]` so it should be like this: -

```
def update
  if @user.update(active: params[:value])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

## update

As you have updated your using block method to change `active` status of user so in this case don't forget to use this `path` and `method` with `button_to`
example: - suppose your path is `user_block_path`
then:-

```
<%= button_to user_block_path(value: false, id: user.id), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  Unblock
<% end %>
```

//controller

```
def block
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(active: params[:value])
end
```